# What to do to select a folder using filechooser in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, filechooser

this is my python code:

```
class Filechooser(Screen):
    def select(self, *args): 
        try: self.label.text = args[1][0] 
        except: pass
    def load(self,path):
        with open(path) as stream:
            global file_directory
            file_directory=stream.read()
        self.dismiss_popup()
```

when I select a folder and click load,then this error was rised:

```
   File "main.py", line 19, in load
     with open(path) as stream:
 PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\movies'
```

it shgows permission error,what should i do

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to do what you want, but I discover you can use tkinter for this task. BTW I'm using a StringProperty to store the path, I don't know if it's the propper way to do this, I'm new to Kivy.

**KV**

```
<BrowseApp>:
    cols: 2
    Button:
        text: 'Browse...'
        size_hint_x: 0.3
        on_release: root.get_path()
    Label:
        id: pathLabel
        text: root.pathVar
```

**PY**

```py
# Import modules
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import *

from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size = (600, 50)

class BrowseApp(GridLayout):
    # variable to store path dir
    pathVar = StringProperty("< Select a folder >")

    # Function to select dir
    def get_path(self):
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.withdraw()
        pathVar = filedialog.askdirectory()
        self.ids.pathLabel.text = pathVar  # Change text of label

# ---- App Class
class loader(App):
    def build(self):
        return BrowseApp()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loader().run()
```